# constructor as default argument

Tags: c++, class

let's say i have 2 classes

```
class B
{
   B() { /* BLA BLA */ };
   B(int a) { /* BLA BLA */ };
   B(int a,int b) { /* BLA BLA */ };
}

class A {
public :
  A(B  par);
}
```

i was wondering how can i call A's constructor with par having a deafult argument, as each of B constructors. (of course i would like see 3 examples, i don't expect all of them to  exist together)

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
A(B par = B())
A(B par = B(1))
A(B par = B(1,2))
```

Full code as per comment:

```
class B
{
public:
   B() {  };
   B(int a) {};
   B(int a,int b) {};
};

class A {
public :
  A(B  par = B()/* or B(1) or B(1,2) */);

};
```

Comment: curious about the reason for downvote..is something wrong in the answer?

Comment: Did you mean to create `par` as object of `B` and pass the same to `A`, then it did not work for me, though I am not the down voter.

Comment: no.. they are the definition of A's constructor with default values for parameter B, I thought OP wanted to know how to specify the default parameters for a user defined type containing parametrized constructors..

Comment: @Naveen thanks, you just can have one of those constructor right?

Comment: Yes..that is what OP also mentioned in the post

Comment: A(B par = B()) or
A(B par = B(1)) or 
A(B par = B(1,2)) would have answered all my questions :).

Answer (score 0):

```
A(B());//create a B object and pass it to A
A(B(1));
A(B(1,2));
```

or define 3 different constructor for A(but that does not sound good to me).